how connect solana to web3modal
I have been using the Web3 Modal to connect my Metamask and Trust Wallet for a while now in the Ethereum and Seoplia chain network but I recently thought of connecting Solana into the available network but Solana do not have a chain Id with the number type to let alone config.
Any idea on how to connect it?

did you get an answer for this
